# SDK for an AI android application that can provide insights about user

Tags: android, machine-learning, geo-location, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to develop an application which notifies the user about his daily activities/ places he visits, is there any corresponding sdk available to use which can provide me contextual awareness about my user?